# Grails - map /file.xml to a controller and action

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

How do I map a uri with a suffix to a controller + action on grails?

I have tried:

```
name sitemap: "/data.xml" {
    controller = 'data'
    action = 'generate'
}
```

But it simply don't work. While this:

```
name sitemap: "/data" {
    controller = 'data'
    action = 'generate'
}
```

works just fine...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you having the problem with?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown there is valid.  See the app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/urlfilemappingdemo.  It contains the following:

```
// grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        name sitemap: "/data.xml" {
            controller = 'data'
            action = 'generate'
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

The default index page includes a link which verifies that this mapping works.

Comment: You haven't clarified what happens in your app aside from asserting "But it simply don't work.".  One thing to look for is a conflicting mapping.

Comment: 404 happens. No exception or anything like that. I have checked for conflicts, but there is none... I'll investigate further. Thanks!